# Sometimes ViewState Variable Is Lost Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using webform (in asp.net 4.5) in my project. 
But sometimes, value's my viewstate variable is lost. 
It just appears just 1 or 2 time in a day.

I have a snippet code in onpreload like that:

```
protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreLoad(e);

        if (!EnableViewState || Form == null)
            return;
        if (Session["postbackError"] != null)
        {
            Session["postbackError"] = null;

            //write this error to log file
            var ex = new Exception("Lost viewstate");
            LogErrorUltil.LogError(ex);
        }
        if (IsPostBack && Form.Attributes["postback"] == null)
        {
            Session["postbackError"] = true;            
        }
        Form.Attributes["postback"] = "1";
    }
```

I see in my log, the message "Lost viewstate" is write in log file.

BUT I sure that:

1. Web.config is not refreshed 

2. App pool of IIS is not recycled.

Can you give me a idea which can make "Lost viewstate" is written to log file except 2 reason above?

I greatly appreciate your ideas.
Thank for your ideas.

Comment: ViewState and Session are two different things.

Comment: Yes, I know that ViewState and Session are two different things. But as you can see in my code, I always set Form.Attributes["postback"] = "1". But I don't know why sometimes, Form.Attributes["postback"] is null in PostBack

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to keep error messages in the session, especially if you save them in a log file.

**Web.config**

`Web.config` is not refreshed?

If you modifi your web.config you need to rebuild your application, so `Form.Attributes["postback"]` will be `null`.

If `Web.config` is not refresh, then `ViewState` will preserve `Form.Attributes["postback"]` value. It's not necessary to set its value for each call of the event `OnPreLoad`. With `OnLoad` event you can set all values that `ViewState` take care.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostback)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Set here all the values that will be maintained by 'ViewState'
    Form.Attributes.Add("postback", "1");
    TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Wheat;

    /* 
       Set runat="server" and enableviewstate="true" on common html elements 
       if you need to preserve it's values and styles between postbacks
    */
}
```

**App pool of IIS is not recycled**

If you recycle App pool you lost `ViewState`, if not, `ViewState` persist between postbacks and is lost when you request another page.

**EnableViewState="false" OR ViewStateMode="Disabled"**
You need to set the value of the `Form.Attributes["postback"]` attribute as you did.

Comment: Is there another reason which can make Exception("Lost viewstate"); appears in my log except 2 reasons:  <br/>1. Refresh web.config.  <br/> 2. App pool of IIS is  recycled  <br/>. Because if the two situations appear, I redirected the user to login page and the exception never is written to log file. I think that there is other reason like user stay a long in the form before clicking save button. It is a reason? Thank for your reply.

Comment: Yes it is. In this [article](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits) you can learn more about connection timeout. Probably this article have what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you mention ViewState many times in your question, but ***your code did not use ViewState***. Instead, it uses ***SessionState***.

`Form.Attributes["postback"] = "1";` is to add an attribute named ***postback*** to ***form*** tag. `<form ... postback="1">`. ***It is not ViewState. The approach is really weird.***

[Default SessionState timeout is 20 minutes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

It means if user accesses the server after 20 minutes of idle, SessionState is no longer valid and it will return null.

If you want more than 20 minutes, you can increase it in ***web.config***.

Comment: I see that my code did not use viewstate. I just make a sample in my code to get ideas about which thing can make "Exception("Lost viewstate")" appears in my code. Session timeout is not a reason of my problem because if session timeout, I redirected user to login page before function is run.